# Input dimension error in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I know this error has been posted several times, but I didn't find any case that matched mine and I really don't understand why this error arises on that particular case.

So I'm trying to finetune a VGG16 network, and as training didn't seem to work if I just changed the output layer and made some earlier layers trainable, I just want to try it by removing the last layers and add new ones back.

Specifically, I remove the top layers up to the last convolution layer, so the network looks like this :

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
=================================================================
Total params: 12,354,880
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 12,354,880
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then I add a convolution layer:

```
vgg16_model_ft.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
```

and it raises the well-known error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

I really don't understand why ndim=2 is found for that new layer, it does not make sense to me, even doing

```
vgg16_model_ft.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=vgg16_model_ft.layers[-1].output_shape))
```

doesn't solve it. But I'm still kind of new to Keras so there must be some subtlety I don't get yet.
I'm using Keras 2.1.5 with a Tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why we are getting this error, but you could try the Functional API

```
model_input=Input(shape=(224,224,3))
vgg16_model_ft=VGG16(include_top=False)(input)
new_model=Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(vgg_model_ft)
new_model=Model(input,new_model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I found it while switching to functional API. Appearently, popping out layers using `model.layers.pop()` does change `model.summary()` but does not change the model itself (unless you compile I guess but I was not doing it before adding all the layers I wanted).
Anyway I was able to do it without the functional API.

Now I have another unrelated problem but I don't know if I should make another post for it ...